# The Value of viewstate is not refelected on the OnItemReorder event of AjaxToolkit:ReorderList Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, reorderlist

I am using AjaxToolkit:ReorderList Control in an asp.net page(C#) and changing value of a viewstate[""] on OnItemReorder event, when I click on any button on the same page the value of viewState is not founded.

Please provide me appropriate solutions.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand it, the OnItemReorder event happens in something other than a regular postback.  Thus, the page is not re-rendered, and consequently the changed ViewState doesn't get sent back to the client.  As a result, when you do a real postback, you send back the original ViewState from before you made the change.

I got around this by storing the data I was trying to sort in a session variable rather than ViewState, but I'm not entirely happy with that.